# Special Wrapping in multiple TextBlocks

Tags: wpf

I got a `ListView` like this:

[image]

my `DataTemplate` looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
              <WrapPanel>                                    
                         <TextBlock Name="tbDoc" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" Text="&#xe022;" Padding="2"  Style="{StaticResource tbDocStyle}" Visibility="{Binding HasDocs, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
                         <TextBlock Name="tbPart" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" Text="&#xe006;" Padding="2" Style="{StaticResource tbPartStyle}"  Visibility="{Binding ET, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}"  />                                    
              </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

So the first 2 `TextBlock`s are fixed at beginning, the last `TextBlock` should wrap his text if it's too long, but with a `WrapPanel` it wraps the whole `TextBlock` away from the first two... how i can do this right?

Comment: Did you try to set the TextWrapping property to NoWrap? And why are you using a WrapPanel?

Comment: i want to wrap the third textblock content

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"  /> ? You may have to replace the WrapPanel with a StackPanel.

Comment: then the textblock content gets not wrapped, it just go further in one line...

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal repo of your issue when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mm8 i described it quite complete, i got three TextBlock's the first two are at the beginning (the icon there), the third TextBlock has Text (sometimes it's too long so the Text should wrap... now it wraps the whole textblock as you can see...